# something about binary tree

Tags: c, data-structures

This code is about binary tree.
It can work well.
But after I press the enter key and get the correct answer,it turns out stopping working.WHY？
[This is the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb0Ju.png)
source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct BiTNode
{
    char data;
    struct BiTNode* rchild;
    struct BiTNode* lchild;
}BiTNode;
typedef BiTNode* BiTree;
int CreateBiTree(BiTree *T);
void Visit(BiTree T);
void PreOrder(BiTree T);
void InOrder(BiTree T);
void PostOrder(BiTree T);

int main(void)
{
    BiTree T;
    CreateBiTree(&T);
    PreOrder(T);
    return 0;
}

int CreateBiTree(BiTree *T)
{
    char data;
    scanf("%c",&data);
    if(data=='#')
    {
        *T==NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        *T=(BiTree)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode));
        (*T)->data=data;
        CreateBiTree(&(*T)->lchild);
        CreateBiTree(&(*T)->rchild);
    }
    return 0;
}

void Visit(BiTree T)
{
        printf("%c",T);
}

void PreOrder(BiTree T)
{
    if(T!=NULL)
    {
        Visit(T);
        PreOrder(T->lchild);
        PreOrder(T->rchild);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the statement `*T==NULL;` will do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] as well as a *clear problem statement*.

Answer (score 1):

In your Code you have many issues :-

1. In CreateBiTree(BiTree *T) function, you only modified single pointer for root, rchild and lchild. you should define Bitree *T locally in this function.
2. what is *T==NULL? Are you initializing or comparing?
3. scanf("%c",&data); this statement will also create a problem in character case. this statement will wait for '\n' also. so you should write scanf(" %c",&data).
4. *T=(BiTree)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode)); this statement is also wrong, malloc return pointer, so you should do correct type casting.         *T=(BiTree *)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode));

i have modified you source code for your reference, have look

```
//it can work
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
typedef struct BiTNode
{
    char data;
    struct BiTNode* rchild;
    struct BiTNode* lchild;
}BiTNode;
typedef BiTNode BiTree;
BiTree *CreateBiTree();
void Visit(BiTree **T);
void PreOrder(BiTree *T);
void InOrder(BiTree T);
void PostOrder(BiTree T);
int main(void)
{
    BiTree *T;
    T=CreateBiTree();
    PreOrder(T);
    return 0;
}
BiTree *CreateBiTree()
{
    BiTree *T;
    char data;
    scanf(" %c",&data);
        printf("............%c\n",data);

    if(data=='#')
        return NULL;

    T=(BiTree *)malloc(sizeof(BiTree));
    T->data=data;

    printf("Enter left child of %c:\n",data);
    T->lchild=CreateBiTree();

    printf("Enter right child of %c:\n",data);
    T->rchild=CreateBiTree();

    return T;
}
void Visit(BiTree **T)
{
        printf("%c",(*T)->data);
}
void PreOrder(BiTree *T)
{
    if(T!=NULL)
    {
        Visit(&T);
        PreOrder(T->lchild);
        PreOrder(T->rchild);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry,but I wanna know what's scand()?(I'm a beginer,student in high school)

Comment: @Bugmaker scand()?

Comment: you write"so you should write scand(" %c",&data)."in the end of #3.  :)

Comment: for #4，BiTree is the pointer to the BiTNode,so *T=(BiTree)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode)) is right?

Comment: It will work but I suggest you do simple code. Simple coding helps you in debugging too.